# how to implement CrossTab in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I want to convert data from format a to format b in PostgreSQL, any help would be great-full.

[reference image with existing format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbCs2.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the  [tablefunc module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tablefunc.html), it contain function that do that.